# À quel point ces expressions sont-elles courantes ?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, argot, langage-informel

J’ai collecté beaucoup d’expressions dans un documentaire mais je ne sais pas si elles se disent vraiment...

Ce sont:

- *à moitié* (sorta, kinda)
- *je suis chaud* (I’m down, I’m up for it, I want to)
- *mais quand même* (don’t mention it)
- *c’est chaud* (it’s complicated)
- *nous y voilà* (I knew it, here we go again)

Comment: Vous demandez trop de choses en une seule question. Il faut limiter les questions à un seul problème.

Comment: Vous avez raison, je vais réviser un peu !

Comment: J'ai du mal à imaginer dans quel contexte *mais quand même* pourrait signifier *don't mention it*. Auriez-vous un exemple ou une mise en contexte ?

Comment: Rien ne vous empêche maintenant d'écrire une nouvelle question pour les trois ou quatre autres expressions que vous avez éliminées de la présente question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some phrases are downright very standard, some others are really recent "teenager slang":

- savoir sur le bout des doigts (to have down pat): correct but more commonly used as *connaître sur le bout des doigts*
- ça fait envie (it’s tempting): correct, quite common
- ça craint un max (it’s dodgy/risky): very colloquial, sounds like "bad boy" slang. It can also mean "disappointing, upsetting" (ex: *J'ai raté mon examen, ça craint*)
- à moitié (sorta, kinda): correct , and is very common. It is rather negative, ie "not so much" (ex: *j'étais à moitié content de mon travail* means you were not really satisfied)
- ça fait deux (we don’t see eye to eye, we don’t go together): correct, quite common in familiar uses, but is always used along with mentioning 2 persons, or more commonly one person and one field of knowledge or expertise (ex: *Moi et les maths, ça fait deux*)
- je suis chaud (i’m down, i’m up for it, i want to): very common nowadays among teenagers, would sound a bit weird in the mouth of anyone above eg 30
- c’est chaud (it’s complicated). same comment as *je suis chaud*. Depending on the context, it can also mean *that's a risky situation* (ex: *c'est chaud pendant les manifs des gilets jaunes, il vaut mieux rester à l'écart*)
- c’est ceinture: the more common phrase is *faire ceinture*, that means *to go without something* (ex: *on doit faire des économies, on va faire ceinture et ne pas partir en vacances*). If used in a certain context, it can be obvious you are talking about sex, it is then used as an innuendo to mean *no sex* (ex: *je n'ai fait que travailler pour mes examens, je n'ai pas vu ma copine, ça a été ceinture pendant un mois !*)
- nous y voilà: can mean plenty of things depending on the context, ie *here we are* when arriving somewhere or *that's what I was waiting for* if you want to express some relief after waiting for something

Comment: this is an amazing response! thank you for the detailed answers and examples! very very much appreciated!

Comment: I agree with most of the rest, but I've never heard *c'est ceinture*.

Comment: I have an example in mind, in the TV series "Vernon Subutex": the protagonist (a man in his 40ies) talks to a young (female) journalist. They agree on some rules for their collaboration. He says abruptly "2ème règle... ceinture !". This is so unexpected that the journalist asks "comment ça, ceinture ? Ca veut dire quoi ?" and he answers clearly "pas de sexe entre nous...".